# Laravel & Guzzle: How to get response body?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, guzzle

I have one more problem: I have an artisan command which access an external API to fetch information. How to access the response body? There are many Guzzle documentations but every tells me something different which is not working. On the laracast discussions someone wrote `$response = getBody()`. Some other said `$response->json()` or something like that.

I looked which methods are available (what PhpStorm tells me), but I wasn't able to find one which solved this problem. Even the questions on Stack Overflow gets answered with `$response->getBody()`.

When I take a look into the Response class of guzzle, there's a public method named "getBody()".
Did I do something wrong? I use Guzzle 3.9.2 (I think it comes with laravel) from the composer repo "guzzle/guzzle".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it. Now I'm using Guzzlehttp/Guzzle version 6.1.1 and everything works fine :)